# How to rename multiple file names by removing white space and characters?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, rename

I have multiple files to rename

```
Eg:
     ERJP00300029 3.13.jpg
     SRKP00100002 12.04.jpg
     ERJP01500001 ERJP12 10.5.jpg
```

I want to rename above file as

```
Eg:
    ERJP00300029.jpg
    SRKP00100002.jpg
    ERJP01500001.jpg
```

How to keep first part name alone.

I used below code but I can't get my exact solution. Where I am mistake.

```
@ECHO ON

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET SourceDir=F:\Ezhilarasan\Exibt\need_upload\ERHP\check
FOR /G "TOKENS=1-3 DELIMS=. " %%G IN ('DIR /B /A-D "%SourceDir%\*.jpg"') DO (
    SET "part1=%%~F" 
    SET "part2=%%~G" 
    SET "part3=%%~H"
    REN "!part1! \%SourceDir%!part2!.!part3!" "!part1!.!part3!"
)
GOTO EOF
```

Comment: I am suppose to do this action in cmd or batch file. So I could not use Bulk Rename Utility. @Scott

Answer (score 0):

Well, there’s several things happening:

1. Is your system set up to use a language other than English? 
   On my (English-based) system,
   the command that you are trying to do is `FOR /F`, not `FOR /G`.
2. You’re extracting three (`1-3`) tokens starting with `%%G`,
   but then you’re using `%%F`, `%%G`, and `%%H`. 
   Nothing is being put into `%%F`. 
   Either change the `FOR` statement to refer to `%%F`,
   or change the loop body to use `%%G`, `%%H`, and `%%I`. 
   Except …
3. … don’t do that. 
   Your approach is flawed. 
   Think about what it means to have period (**`.`**) and space as delimiters. 
   Your filenames get broken into tokens like this:

   ```
                                        #1              #2        #3    #4     #5
   ERJP00300029 3.13.jpg           →    ERJP00300029    3         13    jpg
   SRKP00100002 12.04.jpg          →    SRKP00100002    12        04    jpg
   ERJP01500001 ERJP12 10.5.jpg    →    ERJP01500001    ERJP12    10    5      jpg
   ```

   so,

   - the filename is not always equal to `part1 part2.part3`,
   - the extension not always the third token, and, in fact,
   - for your example filenames, it’s *never* the third token, and
   - it isn’t always the same token number.

   We’ll have to get back to this.
4. What do you think you’re doing with the REN (RENAME) command? 
   Specifically,
   why are you putting `\%SourceDir%` ***between*** `part1` and `part2`? 
   The only hope you have of making this work
   is to put `%SourceDir%\` ***before*** `part1`. 
   And note that the backslash (`\`) needs to come *after* `%SourceDir%`.
5. If this is the complete batch file,
   you don’t need to do anything special at the end. 
   The batch file will exit when it reaches the end. 
   But, if this is part of a larger system,
   you might want to have an explicit terminating command at the end. 
   That command should be `GOTO :EOF`, not `GOTO EOF`.

Not to pile on, but your approach of taking the output from `DIR`
and immediately breaking it down in tokens is flawed. 
Looking at your example names,
the string `ERJP12 10.5` gets broken down into three tokens:
`ERJP12`, `10`, and `5`. 
But `ERJP12.10.5` would get broken down into the same tokens,
and so would `ERJP12 10 5` and `ERJP12.10 5`. 
You can’t reconstruct the original (i.e., current, existing) filenames
from the tokens;
you need to ***capture*** the original filename intact, and then break it down.

I don’t see why you need to run `DIR`. 
All you need is `FOR %%F IN ("%SourceDir%\*.jpg") DO`;
it will give you the names of *files* only (no subdirectories),
and, unlike the output of `DIR`,
it will include the name of the source directory
(the directory that contains the files). 
Now that we have the complete current file pathname in `%%F`,
we can start to break it down. 
*Now* we use `FOR /F`. 
So, take the file **n**ame portion of `%%F`,
and pull out a token that is the first part **a**lone. 
Then rename the original full pathname
to the first part plus the e**x**tension. 
Here’s the complete batch file:

```
SET SourceDir=F:\Ezhilarasan\Exibt\need_upload\ERHP\check
FOR %%F IN ("%SourceDir%\*.jpg") DO (
    FOR /F "DELIMS=. " %%A IN ("%%~nF") DO (
        REN "%%F" "%%A%%~xF"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with every of Scott's very detailed explanations
in this special case a simple

```
@Echo On
Pushd F:\Ezhilarasan\Exibt\need_upload\ERHP\check
FOR /F  %%G IN ('DIR /B /A-D "*.jpg"') DO REN "%%G*.jpg" %%G.jpg
PopD
```

would do equally.
The default is `for /f "tokens=1 delims= "`
The dir returns only files with the ext jpg so we can use it literally in the rename.